# 'how reasoning and acting more human-like works'

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

This is from [one of "for dummies series"](https://www.dummies.com/book/technology/information-technology/ai/general-ai/artificial-intelligence-for-dummies-281623/).

> Our current daily data production is estimated to amount to about 2.5
> quintillion (a number with 18 zeros) bytes, with the lion’s share
> going to unstructured data like videos and audios. All this data is
> related to common human activities, feelings, experiences, and
> relations. Roaming through this data, an AI can easily learn how
> *reasoning and acting* more human-like **works**.

I wonder why 'works' in bold is singular even though the subject of how-clause is plural, that is '*reasoning and acting*'.
(We have not 'or' but 'and' in "*reasoning and acting*")

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I edited it. Thank you.

Comment: Specifically, "reasoning and acting" is one thing (with two aspects), not two separate things, and therefore is treated as singular. I think "works" is a bit of an odd choice: it doesn't really understand how human brains work, it is just able to mimic them. But it's defensible because it's hard to describe what an AI does using everyday words.

Comment: @StuartF I understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: "reasoning and acting ... more human-like" sounds very clumsy. "...reasoning more like a human" would fit better, as an adverb phrase instead of an adjective.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty You read my thoughts! Thank you so much for explaining what I was wondering about.